# Pulling an object with a spring balance simulation in unity 3d/2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, physics

I'm new to unity. Am planning to use unity to do a simulation for pulling an object with a spring balance for a science class.

variables im looking at are :

1)the mass of object being pulled
2)the surface texture

both of these variables will have a side by side comparison when it is on a flat surface and one on the ramp.

These will give the various reading on the spring balance.

Something like this :https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nagwa.com%2Fen%2Fworksheets%2F208120728128%2F&psig=AOvVaw304EyQgEtjfDyivKzXCTHK&ust=1669538232114000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjRxqFwoTCNigp964y_sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

May i know which project I can take a look at to be able to simulate such project?

I have tried looking for such simulation online but am unable to find them and the ones on youtube are not helpful. If you are able to point me in the right direction to start this project that would be helpful.

Comment: No project necessary.  Unity has this out-of-the-box and can be done completely in the **Editor**.  _Zero code_.

Comment: Member for 5 years should be aware of _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_